# iOS UITextView AttributedString uppercase extension image name issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I want to show the url image in UITextView.
Server image  name is in **uppercase extension**.

Image name: asset(8).JPG

Image url:
http://example.com/**asset(8).JPG**

My code is:

```html
NSString *htmlString=@"<html><img src=\"http://example.com/coil-web/files/nqr330qqcbcptmstpl4/asset(8).JPG\" height=\"100\" width=\"100\"></html>";

NSMutableAttributedString *htmlStringAttributedString=[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[htmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] options:@{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType } documentAttributes:nil error:nil];

self.textview.attributedText=htmlStringAttributedString
```

But it shows only white file with html name in UITextView.

Got NSMutableAttributedString as follows:

```html
{
    NSAttachment = "<NSTextAttachment: 0x7f82f076fb40> \"asset(8).JPG.html\"";
    NSColor = "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1";
    NSFont = "<UICTFont: 0x7f82f0774ac0> font-family: \"Times New Roman\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 12.00pt";
    NSKern = 0;
    NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 4, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n), DefaultTabInterval 36, Blocks (null), Lists (null), BaseWritingDirection 0, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningFactor 0, HeaderLevel 0";
    NSStrokeColor = "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1";
    NSStrokeWidth = 0;
}
```

Its image then Why NSAttachment shows **asset(8).JPG.html** . Whats .html??

My code is working for small extension image name.I want to display html text in text view.

Comment: You're expecting it to show you a link or the image itself?

Comment: The NSAttachment value not proper. 

NSAttachment = "<NSTextAttachment: 0x7f82f076fb40> \"asset(8).JPG.html\"";
I receive an html here where as i am expecting an image.
Like this :
NSAttachment = "<NSTextAttachment: 0x7ff7933d9a20> \"capture(106).jpg\"";

This issue occurs only when image passed in NSMutableAttributedString has extension in upper case (xyz.JPG )